# Changing your bullet points in beamer block, maybe boadilla?

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

Can anyone give me a list of the different styles of bullets in `beamer`? 
I am looking for the command that will give me the typical 3d looking blue ball in a block I know where to input it in my 
`\item [\...?....]`

I think I'm looking for `\usepackage{boadilla}`
but i don't know how to get this.

help a newbie out?

Answer (score 26):

There are four predefined styles for the `itemize items` or `enumerate items` templates controlling the aspect for the labels in an `itemize`, respectively `enumerate`, environment: these are `default`(`triangle`), `square`, `circle` and `ball`; the following simple example shows these four styles for an `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First item.
  \item Second item.
  \item Third item.
  \end{itemize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First item.
  \item Second item.
  \item Third item.
  \end{itemize}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First item.
  \item Second item.
  \item Third item.
  \end{itemize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First item.
  \item Second item.
  \item Third item.
  \end{itemize}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can choose an appropriate theme having the desired style or, you can change to the desired style in any theme by setting the template as in my example above.

If you want the style, let's say `ball`, to apply globally to all the `itemize` environments, move the line

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
```

or

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[ball]
```

(for the `enumerate` environments) to the preamble. To affect both `enumerate` and `itemize` environments, use the `items` template instead:

```
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
```

Comment: @steph You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept an answer that you consider solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use the Boadilla **theme**, not package. Try

```
\usetheme{Boadilla}
```

in your preamble. This is case-sensitive. Look at http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/ for a good overview of themes, stacked vertically.

Edit: Since I linked to that matrix: what you are seeing along the horizontal axis are colors, which can be changed by the command

```
\usecolortheme{albatross}
```

in your preamble. Combining these give a large variety of styles.