# changing all the itemize into bullets in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, itemize, bullets

how can I set all the item into bullets (cobalt)?

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=cyan} %background color
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=blue} %colore titoli
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=yellow,bg=cyan} %colore e background in un comando


%%% duplicated <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%%\usepackage{tikz}
%%\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
%%\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
%%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
%%\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
%%\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67} 
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=cobalt,bg=violet!50}    

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
 %\usetikzlibrary{calc} %rido <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cobalt} % all frames will have cobalt bullets

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=5mm} %margini

%\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logo.jpeg}}
\title{\textbf{title } \\
     \vspace{20pt}
      \includegraphics[height=50pt]{logo.jpeg}}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
\author{name}

\institute[VFU] % (optional)
{%
%  \inst{1}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  department\\
  Uni
  \and
%  \inst{2}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  speker\\
  speaker 2
}

\date[VLC 2013] % (optional)
{date}

%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=violet!20} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=cobalt,bg=violet!50} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Title first slide} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed

%\begin{figure}[h]%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\centering%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{itemize}
\item bla blla
\item gla gla
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171705/changing-your-bullet-points-in-beamer-block-maybe-boadilla

Comment: tried all the command but nothing change

Comment: @Noob_Latex: It worked in your example code (see [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/9yGeJLVG)). Just add `\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]` before `\begin{document}`.